# nested select or join query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am new to sql so this may have a very basic answer but the question to answer is as follows .....

**which film has taken the least takings at a performance? include film name and cinema name in the result.?**

**film name** and **cinema name** are in two different table **film** and **cinema**. **takings** are in the **performance** table. i cant figure out how to complete this query. this is what i have got so far but it comes with an **error in line 3 column 7.**

```
select cinema_no,film_no
from CINEMA, film
where takings ( select min(takings)
from performance);
```

Comment: Please review [ask] before asking questions on Stack Overflow so that we can provide answers to your questions that will be helpful for others with the same or similar problems.

Comment: dinesh forget about using commas between table names in the from clause, it is a bad habit to get into. **nb** `from cinema, film` **multiplies** every film by every cinema. What you need are some `inner join`s but we do not have sufficient information

Comment: Regardless of any kind of programming (in *any* language), whenever the requester asks about MIN this or MAX that, your first question should always be: "Are ties possible (for lowest - or highest - value), and in that case what is the desired output?" For example, what if the lowest takings were a tie between three different films, at different cinemas? Should all three pairs be shown? Only one of them, and if so which one? Or - and this is always a possibility - is there a way to GUARANTEE that ties will never be possible in the given problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the structure (fields and data types) of the tables which are involved in this query. Without that information there's not much anyone can do to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because of multiple tags with `oracle`, I ignored the tag `mysql` ( *of one which you should get rid of. e.g. please decide which `DBMS` are you using, by the way I already removed the irrelevant one `oracle-sqldeveloper`* ).

It seems you need such a select statement ( *prefer using modern **ANSI-92 JOIN** syntax, easily maintained and understandable* ) with ordering by descending `sum` and contribution of `row_number` function as :

```
SELECT Name, Sum_Takings 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT f.Name, sum(p.Takings) Sum_Takings,
          row_number() over (ORDER BY sum(p.Takings)) as rn
     FROM Film f 
     LEFT JOIN Cinema c ON f.Cinema_ID = c.ID
     LEFT JOIN Performance p ON f.ID = p.id_film
    GROUP BY f.Name
   )
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

with added `DDL` statement as in the following :

```
SQL>  CREATE TABLE Cinema (
  2     ID     integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3     Title  varchar2(100) NOT NULL
  4   );

Table created

SQL>  CREATE TABLE Film (
  2     ID   integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3     Name varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  4     Cinema_ID integer
  5       CONSTRAINT fk_Cinema_ID REFERENCES Cinema(ID)
  6   );

Table created

SQL>   CREATE TABLE Performance (
  2     ID      integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  3     ID_Film integer
  4          CONSTRAINT fk_Film_ID REFERENCES Film(ID),
  5     Takings integer
  6   );

Table created

SQL>  INSERT ALL
  2         INTO Cinema(ID,Title) VALUES(1,'NiteHawk')
  3         INTO Cinema(ID,Title) VALUES(2,'Symphony Space')
  4         INTO Cinema(ID,Title) VALUES(3,'The Ziegfeld')
  5         INTO Cinema(ID,Title) VALUES(4,'Cinema Village')
  6       SELECT * FROM dual;

4 rows inserted

SQL>  INSERT ALL
  2         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(1,'Citizen Kane',1)
  3         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(2,'Titanic',2)
  4         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(3,'Brave Heart',4)
  5         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(4,'Dumb and Dummer',3)
  6         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(5,'How To Train Your Dragon',2)
  7         INTO Film(ID,Name,Cinema_ID) VALUES(6,'Beetle Juice',3)
  8       SELECT * FROM dual;

6 rows inserted

SQL>  INSERT ALL
  2         INTO Performance VALUES(1,1,15)
  3         INTO Performance VALUES(2,1,4)
  4         INTO Performance VALUES(3,2,10)
  5         INTO Performance VALUES(4,3,1)
  6         INTO Performance VALUES(5,4,5)
  7         INTO Performance VALUES(6,3,3)
  8         INTO Performance VALUES(7,2,7)
  9         INTO Performance VALUES(8,5,7)
 10         INTO Performance VALUES(9,6,6)
 11       SELECT * FROM dual;

9 rows inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> SELECT Name, Sum_Takings
  2    FROM
  3    (
  4     SELECT f.Name, sum(p.Takings) Sum_Takings,
  5            row_number() over (ORDER BY sum(p.Takings)) as rn
  6       FROM Film f
  7       LEFT JOIN Cinema c ON f.Cinema_ID = c.ID
  8       LEFT JOIN Performance p ON f.ID = p.id_film
  9      GROUP BY f.Name
 10     )
 11    WHERE rn = 1
 12  ;

NAME                                                                  SUM_TAKINGS
--------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
Brave Heart                                                                     4
```

[***dbfiddle.uk demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ec76db53517aacecea1c2fa979889fc8)

Answer (score 0):

As it involves grouping of Performance table you can achieve it by using two queries one to get the cinemaID and filmID of minimum performance takings and the another one to get the cinema name and filmname using the collected ids

> SELECT CinemaID,FilmID from Performance where
>   PerformanceTaking=(Select Min(PerformanceTaking) from Performance);
>
> SELECT CinemaName,FilmName from Cinema,Film where CinemaID=1 and
>   FilmID=1;

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from (select c.cinema_name,f.film_name
from cinema c, film f,performance p,
rank() over (partition by c.cinema order by sum(p.takings)) as rank
where
c.ID=f.cinema_id and
f,id=p.id
group by f.film_name) where rank=1
;
```